# How can I use a CustomConverter with Dozer to convert multiple entities into one entity with a list field?

Tags: converters, dozer

I have a list of entities which in turn have a field of another (Embeddable) type. 

All these entities shall be converted into a single bean which holds a list of these embeddable types.
Prior to using Dozer I have written a conversion method. I have put this into the dozerBeanMapping.xml:

```
<custom-converters>
    <converter type="com.foo.bar.helper.ChargingPoiEntityToPoiConverter" >
        <class-a>com.foo.bar.services.charging.repository.ChargingPoiEntity</class-a>
        <class-b>com.foo.bar.beans.ChargingPoi</class-b>
  </converter>
</custom-converters>
```

I instantiate Dozer this way:

```
final Mapper mapper = DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.getInstance();
```

Which map method do I have to invoke? 
Using

```
mapper.map(cpEntities, Cp.class);
```

my custom converter is not invoked.

Trying to invoke

```
mapper.map(cpEntities.get(0), Cp.class);
```

works well, but I have to convert a List<*ChargingPoiEntity*> instead of a single *ChargingPoiEntity*.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapper.map(cpEntities, Cp.class);` is not matching your custom converter because the generic type information in `List<ChargingPoiEntity>` is lost. Dozer sees the class of cpEntities as `java.util.ArrayList`, which does not match `com.foo.bar.services.charging.repository.ChargingPoiEntity`. My understanding is that this is a limitation of Java generics, not an issue in Dozer.

One workaround is to define a custom converter between a ChargingPoiEntity array and a ChargingPoi:

```
<custom-converters>
  <converter type="com.foo.bar.helper.ChargingPoiEntityToPoiConverter" >
    <class-a>[Lcom.foo.bar.services.charging.repository.ChargingPoiEntity;</class-a>
    <class-b>com.foo.bar.beans.ChargingPoi</class-b>
  </converter>
</custom-converters>
```

When mapping, you can convert the cpEntities list to an array:

```
ChargingPoiEntity[] entityArray = cpEntities.toArray(
            new ChargingPoiEntity[cpEntities.size()]);
ChargingPoi convertedList = mapper.map(entityArray, ChargingPoi.class);
```

Note that in this case, the custom converter will not be invoked when you do

```
mapper.map(cpEntities.get(0), ChargingPoi.class);
```

This problem should only apply when attempting to map generic collections directly via mapper.map(...); entities containing generic collections as fields should map fine.

Comment: Yes, mapping entities containing generic collections works well. I wonder if it could be possible to provide the type information by a further input parameter to the map method!?